# Python dictionary merge of two list and let values be clubbed together in a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two list containing subnets and idea to merge them in such a values that value with same key be put together in a list

```
agg = [
            '10.109.0.0/16',
            '10.109.0.0/16',
            '10.109.0.0/16',
            '9.16.0.0/16',
            '9.16.0.0/16',
            '9.16.0.0/16'
        ]
subnet = [
            '10.109.0.0/19',
            '10.109.32.0/19',
            '10.109.64.0/19',
            '9.16.17.0/24',
            '9.16.18.0/24',
            '9.16.19.0/24'
        ]
result = {
            '10.109.0.0/16':['10.109.0.0/19','10.109.32.0','10.109.64.0'],
            '9.16.0.0/16' : ['9.16.17.0/24','9.16.18.0/24','9.16.19.0/24']
        }
```

Comment: There are missing informations, please refer to the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use defaultdict to get the result more effectively.

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
list1 = [
        '10.109.0.0/16',
        '10.109.0.0/16',
        '10.109.0.0/16',
        '9.16.0.0/16',
        '9.16.0.0/16',
        '9.16.0.0/16'
    ]
list2 = [
        '10.109.0.0/19',
        '10.109.32.0/19',
        '10.109.64.0/19',
        '9.16.17.0/24',
        '9.16.18.0/24',
        '9.16.19.0/24'
    ]

for a, b in zip(list1, list2):
    result[a].append(b)
result = dict(result)
print(result)
```

Comment: `result = dict(result)` is required to produce the expected output.

Answer (score -1):

In python, you can use the `zip` method to iterate over two lists **of the same length**. We can use this to add to your results dictionary:

```
result = {}
list1 = [
        '10.109.0.0/16',
        '10.109.0.0/16',
        '10.109.0.0/16',
        '9.16.0.0/16',
        '9.16.0.0/16',
        '9.16.0.0/16'
    ]
list2 = [
        '10.109.0.0/19',
        '10.109.32.0/19',
        '10.109.64.0/19',
        '9.16.17.0/24',
        '9.16.18.0/24',
        '9.16.19.0/24'
    ]

for a, b in zip(list1, list2):
    try:
        result[a].append(b)

    except KeyError:
        # Create list if list doesn't exist for that key yet
        result[a] = []
        result[a].append(b)

print(result)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This assumes the lists are both of a particular length and in a particular order.

Comment: @MitchellOlislagers As mentioned in the answer! The question was not about detecting that the lists are of the same length/correct order

Comment: I'm not saying the code doesn't work in this example or that the length/order of the lists should be detected. I'm saying that this code breaks if the order is changed or if the lengths of the lists are unequal. It would be better and more robust to aggregate by detecting matching prefixes of the key and values.